# How to get random string from array every (x) amount of seconds (SWIFT 3)(SPRITEKIT)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I was wondering how I can get a random string from an array every (x) amount of seconds and display it into an SKLabelNode. In this case, every 3 seconds.

So far this code displays a random string out of my array, I just need to add a timer so a different string is printed every couple seconds.

The SKLabelNode I want the random string printed to is "colorClick"

Here's the array itself: let whichcolortoclick = ["Blue Box" , "Red Box" , "Pink Box" , "Yellow Box"]

```
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(whichcolortoclick.count)))
        colorClick.text = (whichcolortoclick[randomIndex])
```

To summarize, all I'm really asking for is to add a timer and display a random string from the array every couple seconds. THEN, display it in the colorClick LabelNode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SKAction repeat forever for that (do not use NSTimers in SpriteKit).

Something like this

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let actionUpdateLabel = SKAction.run { [weak self] in
         self?.updateTextLabel()
    }
    let actionDelay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3) // swap this with the update action if you want to have the delay first.
    let sequenceUpdateLabel = SKAction.sequence([actionUpdateLabel, actionDelay])
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequenceUpdateLabel))
}

func updateTextLabel() {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(whichcolortoclick.count)))
    colorClick.text = (whichcolortoclick[randomIndex])
}
```

Hope this helps